# Complexity of range sum query in a quad tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, quadtree

I want to solve a problem that gives the (integral) coordinates of n points (n<=10^5)
and asks q queries (q<=10^4). In each query it gives the (integral) coordinates of two other points and we need to answer how many of the n points are located within the rectangle created by those two points.

(edit) Also the coordinates are huge (x,y <= 10^9) (/edit)

I created a quad tree and then used this function to get the answer, however i get time limit exceeded (time limit = 2s). Is this approach too slow or have I done something wrong?

```
int sum(int left, int right, int down, int up, int i=1, int begx=0, int endx=1e9, int begy=0, int endy=1e9)
{
    if (!i || left>right || down>up) return 0;
    if (left==begx && right==endx && down==begy && up==endy) return num[i];
    int midx = (begx+endx)/2, midy = (begy+endy)/2;
    return  sum(left,min(midx,right),down,min(midy,up),child[i][0],begx,midx,begy,midy)
        +   sum(left,min(midx,right),max(midy+1,down),up,child[i][1],begx,midx,midy+1,endy)
        +   sum(max(midx+1,left),right,down,min(midy,up),child[i][2],midx+1,endx,begy,midy)
        +   sum(max(midx+1,left),right,max(midy+1,down),up,child[i][3],midx+1,endx,midy+1,endy);
}
```

If I comment this function out (and don't answer the queries, just add the points to the quad tree) I get an execution time of about 0.2 secs.
Array `num` stores the sum of a node and `child` stores the index of the four children of each node. Node 0 is dummy. The partitioning of a rectangle in children looks like this:

```
 ___
|1 3|
|0 2|
 ---
```

Comment: Have you checked how deep your tree is? Depending on data distribution and insertion order it may degenerate into something like a list, which can be very slow.

Comment: I generated a big testcase and checked it: the tree is 30 nodes deep, but for some queries, my sum function visits up to 2000 nodes, which is quite large and unexpected!

Comment: In theory, a tree with depth 7 should be able to contain 16000 points, but I suppose depth 30 is not so bad. Having 2000 nodes for 10^5 points however indicates a rather basic quadtree with max 4 children per node. Implementations that allow more children (maybe 10?) per node (before splitting) can be much more efficient. Also, it may be worth checking your dataset and queries. If the dataset is strongly clustered and if queries cover the whole clusters, or if queries cover the whole area (in at least in dimension), then the queries may be may to traverse large parts of the tree.

Comment: For large queries and/or clustered data, a brute force search on a list may be simpler (you only have 10^5) after all). Also, have a look at R-Trees/kd-trees, they may be more efficient for your use case.